# Hyperlink in Android Market description

Tags: android, google-play

How to publish a hyperlink in the Android Market description? I've tried to insert something like this: `<a href="http://m.url.co.uk/somepage.aspx"></a>` in the description, but it shows the exact HTML code instead of a clickable link.

I've seen it done on another Market page so it is possible, but how?

**Answer**: For the web site it was enough to write the HTTP address. On the device Market it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Can you point to the app that has done this? I very curious, since I've tried my self, but cannot figure out how to get the description to link to another app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have also not been able to insert an anchor-tag style descriptive hyperlink in the "Description" field.

That said, it looks like https://market.android.com/details?id=net.timessquareball.app achieves this by simply writing out the entire URL as text (which does work).  We've used this method in our app description as well.

If you're interested, I've experimented with a bit of other markup in the "Description" field and blogged about it [here](https://appendixk.thejameskearney.me/articles/2011/09/android-market-app-description-markup.html).

Comment: Putting in a link to another app doesn't seem to work for me. If I put  https://market.android.com/details?id=net.timessquareball.app in my app description, it appears as text and not a link.

Comment: I don't know how but this guy managed to put hyperlinks with custom text and that is even clickable on desktop. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sentio.desktop&hl=en

Answer (score 5):

A URL of the following form will be converted to a clickable link and will redirect to the address specified in YOUR_URL.

https://www.google.com/url?q=YOUR_URL

eg: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=domain.company.appname

Comment: @Murphy, How it will work for emails such as: email@domain.com? it its showing as text not a link, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to provide your android market app link:

1. [market://details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox](http://market://details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox)
2. http://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

For more info, check this: [How to link to Android Market app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239478/how-to-link-to-android-market-app)

Comment: No, I want to link from within  the App Description. When you publish an application there is a description text. That text is appears to be plain in the developer's console, yet I've seen people inserting and formatiign clickable hyperlinks, for example: https://market.android.com/details?id=net.timessquareball.app, there i sa link to their FAQ page.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, writing just the address http://m.url.co.uk/somepage.aspx, without any tags, makes the link clickable on the Android Market Web Page.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems linking from one app description to another app in Android Market.
Linking to a site outside Market works OK - just type the http:// link without any tags.

So my solution is to link to page on my own website, which redirects to the other app in Market - like I do here : [keyboard for Maxikeys](https://market.android.com/details?id=dk.hhenne.android.hh_int_black)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you will have to post the link without any  tags around for example - https://example.com

This should work!

Comment: The accepted answer tells the same thing. Please [edit] your answer, so that it gives a different solution altogether, or remove it.