# Allow all 'market://' links from inside a webview to open Google Play store

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I have some links in my webview that are market:// links. When my users tap on them, it gives them a page cannot be found error.

How can I allow all links that begin with market:// to automatically open the Google play store when they are tapped? I tried:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

but that didn't seem to do anything. I am pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated. Also, FYI, I cannot change the market:// links to play.google.com myself. They are from my advertiser.

Is there anyway I can include it in this code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView paramWebView, String paramString) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Log.e("shouldOverride", paramString);
        if (Uri.parse(paramString).getHost()!=null && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().equals("market.android.com")) && (!paramString.contains("facebook.com")) && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().contains("twitter.com")) && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().equals("play.google.com"))
                && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().contains("bit.ly")) && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().contains("plus.google.com")) && (!Uri.parse(paramString).getHost().contains("youtube.com"))){
            if(isAppOrGamePage(paramString)){
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("app_url", paramString);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else
                return false;
        } else {
            final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(paramString));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, this question is linked from the official [**Spotify API** Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/content-linking-guide/)  *...(ironic, the OP has <100 rep!)*

Answer (score 16):

You can decide what to do by looking the scheme of the url, if Google Play Store app is installed you can open the detail page in Play Store app, else you can show Google Play web page of the application

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme().equals("market")) {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
                host.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                view.loadUrl("http://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code like this also if its help you:

```
// It will not work in android simulator as it does not have Google Play Store
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+APP_ID)));
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I have updated my original post with a snippet of my code. Please take a look if you have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (url.startsWith("market://")||url.startsWith("vnd:youtube")||url.startsWith("tel:")||url.startsWith("mailto:"))
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
 }
```