# Android studio never recognizing phone on first try

Tags: android, android-studio, nexus-5

I'm testing on a Nexus 5, with Android Studio, on a Mac. I used to be able to just plug my phone into my laptop, but lately when I go to run my app, it doesn't detect my phone.

In order to fix this, I have to go into the phone's Developer Options -> Select USB configuration -> toggle between all the modes until one of them works. Before it would just be MTP, but for some reason it seems to be pretty random which one actually does the trick now.

USB debugging is on. I haven't revoked any debugging authorizations... I know this isn't a huge problem, because I can just mess around with it to make it work, but it's super annoying since it does this every time my laptop goes to sleep, close Android studio, or unplug my phone.

Comment: are you using genymotion at the same time?

Comment: @LeonardArnold no, I don't have any emulators running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow all 'market://' links from inside a webview to open Google Play store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555040/allow-all-market-links-from-inside-a-webview-to-open-google-play-store)

Comment: @AmitVaghela no this is not related...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I simply changed the USB cable and then everything was working fine. Hope this helps...

Comment: using several different USB cables in various states of wear and tear doesn't seem to make much of a difference. I did discover that unplugging it and plugging it back in (and switching USB ports randomly) seems to work at about the same frequency as messing about in the developer options. So about 30% of the time it's OK...

Comment: @JCLaHoot try changing the `adb` port?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is there a way to do it without the command line that's just somewhere in Android Studio?